# Is there a way to merge two nested array based on common key

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

This are the two array that needs merging based on common id, the nested array should also be merged

First Array

```
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, name: "sai", accounts: ["a"] },
    { id: 2, name: "King", accounts:[] },
    { id: 3, name: "Queen", accounts:["c"] },
    { id: 4, name: "kai", accounts:["e"] },
  ];
```

Second Array

```
const arr2 = [
    { id: 1, age: 23, accounts: ["b"] },
    { id: 2, age: 24, accounts:[] },
    { id: 3, age: 25, accounts:["d"] }
  ];
```

Output should be

```
[  
  { id: 1, age: 23, name:"sai", accounts: ["a","b"] },
  { id: 2, age: 24, name: "King", accounts:[] },
  { id: 3, age: 25, name:"Queen", accounts:["c","d"] },
  { id: 4, name: "kai", accounts:["e"] },
]
```

Comment: Please **[edit] the question** to show your own efforts at solving this, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, name: "sai", accounts: ["a"] },
    { id: 2, name: "King", accounts:[] },
    { id: 3, name: "Queen", accounts:["c"] },
    { id: 4, name: "kai", accounts:["e"] },
];

const arr2 = [
    { id: 1, age: 23, accounts: ["b"] },
    { id: 2, age: 24, accounts:[] },
    { id: 3, age: 25, accounts:["d"] }
];

const result = arr1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]));
```

New version:

```
const mergeArrays = () => {
   let res = [];
   
   for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
       let item = arr1[i];
       
       if (arr2[i] && arr1[i].id == arr2[i].id) {
            item.age = arr2[i].age;
            item.accounts = item.accounts.concat(arr2[i].accounts);
       }
       
       res.push(item);
   }
   
   return res;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. However, Your answer did merge the array but it didn't merge accounts array inside of array.

Comment: This does not seem to merge `accounts`. Also it assumes the indexes are the same, but the question asks for a merge based on `id`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the new version.

Comment: The updated code assumes that every `id` that exists in both arrays will be found *at the same index in both arrays*. That may be true for the example data, but if something changes in the data then that assumption may be invalidated, and this code will break.